# Did I use z-test correctly in this problem?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-test

The problem:

It has been said that it is difficult to distinguish Coke and Pepsi by taste alone, without the visual cue of the bottle or can. In an experiment that I did in a class at Stanford, 10 cups were filled at random with either Coke or Pepsi. A student volunteer tasted each of the 10 cups and correctly named the contents of seven. Is this sufficient evidence to conclude that the student can tell apart Coke and Pepsi?

---

My answer:

According to the question, we define the null and Alternative hypotheses:

- Null hypothesis (H0): The student cannot distinguish between Coke and Pepsi by taste alone.
- Alternative hypothesis (Ha): The student can distinguish between Coke and Pepsi by taste alone.

Mathematically, we say: 0: wrong answer and 1: correct answer

[image: Formula]

According to the z-table, the p-value for a z-value of 4 is approximately 0.00001. Since 0.00001 is smaller than 0.05, we reject the null hypothesis. We are convinced that the student **can** distinguish Coke and Pepsi by taste.

I guess I have followed the process correctly, but the z-value and p-value seem a bit strange! 0.00001 is very small value!

Comment: In HW problems, the math often works out neatly. I don't see any errors. 


As for your p value, you might want to check the table, or use an online calculator, or R or whatever.

Comment: You might be interested in a problem called “the lady tasting tea”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common trap when calculating the $z$-transform of a binomial random variable that represents a Bernoulli experiment: confounding the number $x$ of positive outcomes with the mean $\bar x$, which in the present example would be $\bar x = 7/10$, not $7$.

For the $z$-transform, divide by the SE of the statistic you used, which in your case is $\sigma$, not $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$, since you denoted by $\bar x$ the number of positive outcomes.